# Why is this Python function not returning a future?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with NDB. I've removed a lot of code for brevity, but kept the basic problem. I'm getting an error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_result'`

```
def get_future(keys):
    future = ndb.get_multi_async(keys)
    important_value = ... # get important value
    return {"future" : future, "value" : important_value}

dic = get_future(keys)
future = dic['future']
# error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_result'`
items = future.get_result()
```

Why am I getting a list back when I should be getting a future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get_multi_async` actually returns a list of `future` objects, so you would need to call `.get_result()` on those objects.

[Official definition](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions#get_multi_async):

> **ndb.get_multi_async(keys, **ctx_options)**
>
> Asynchronously fetches entities identified by the passed sequence of keys.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> ```
> keys
>  -Sequence of keys
>
> **ctx_options 
>  -Context options
> ```
>
> **Returns a list of Future objects**. Each future's result is a Model instance or None if the key wasn't found.